# Invisible icon for Winter Bash in top bar

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar, winter-bash

A picture says more than a thousand words ...

[image: image of top bar with an apparent empty space between the 'help' and 'hamburger' icon]

I'm pretty sure the Winter Bash icon is supposed to be visible there, but only [after the upcoming UTC midnight](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I literally came to ask about that!

Comment: I thought they redesigned the top bar and was looking for an announcement post to complain about it :p

Comment: Will be fixed after 14 hours 20 minutes 13 seconds ..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> sorry, jumped the gun
> errant gap has been removed
> Winter Bash coming

[image: game of thrones meme about winter bash coming]

Comment: 'W' is actually three syllables. But thanks for the quick fix!

Comment: Not if you say it really fast, then it is only 2.4 syllables, round-down to 2. "dubbya"

Comment: Now [when you refresh the webpage the hamburger disappears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkpGW.gif) for a moment; should have called it Hamburger Bash.

Comment: Maybe the winter chickens of the bash did it? (Speaking of which, are there going to be winter chickens?)